# How to access UIButton via tag in Swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

Objective-C

```
UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tmpTag];
```

How to make this in Swift ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Swift, this would look like this:

```
var tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(tmpTag) as? UIButton
```

It is more or less a direct translation, except the cast is at the other end of the expression.

Comment: I didi this on my own `var sasaButton = self.view.viewWithTag(22) as UIButton` it is same as your but just without `?`. So, can you please tell me for what is `?`in your code.

Comment: @WebOrCode I used `?` to make variable optional, in case the tagged view is not there. If you are 100% certain that the tagged view is there, dropping `?` is fine.

Comment: @webOrCode In Swift 2.0 you have to use ! or ? for unwrapping.

Comment: Why the tag can't be = 0 for a button ?
`var tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(0) as? UIButton`
`print(tmpButton) // Output: nil`

Comment: @HassanTaleb Is the control with tag zero not a `UIButton`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , it is a UIButton builded programmatically using a for loop , I build 4 buttons : `for i in 0..<4 { let button = UIButton(type: .system) // ... } `

Comment: I think there is some confusion in the comments above about `as?`.  This operator performs a check to see if one type is castable to another. If the cast is not successful it will return `nil`. This is different to the downcast operator `as!` which will result in a crash if the cast fails. Confusion was inevitable after the Swift language designers allowed the operators `?` and `!` to have different meanings depending on the context.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Swifty as a C into swift converter and convert your code and get the answer, using this [link](https://objectivec2swift.com/?_ga=2.161670264.574365624.1583131848-1339155074.1582961467#/converter/code/).

Objective-C code

```
UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tmpTag];
```

Swift code

```
let tmpButton = view.viewWithTag(tmpTag) as? UIButton
```

Comment: This solution is the effectively the same as the accepted answer, so it was unfair to vote it down. I found it more interesting than the accepted answer, as it makes the suggestion to use a tool called Swiftify to do Objective-C to Swift translations. One interesting difference between this answer and the accepted one is that it omits the `self`. I checked whether it still works without `self` and it did. According to Ray Wenderlich's style guide, you should omit `self` whenever the compiler accepts it